# Intersection of 2 Random Arrays - Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested

first time here. My problem is that my code is giving me an exception bounds error and I can't figure out why. I just need the code to print the intersecting values without duplicates. Thanks for the help in advance, if you need anymore info please ask.

I CANNOT USE ANYTHING BUT ARRAYS, NO HASH OR ARRAY LIST.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArraySort
{

    static int i,j,k,c=0;
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int [] x = new int [50];
        Random generator = new Random();
        System.out.println("Values in array X:");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            x[i] = generator.nextInt(20);
            // count = count + 1;
            System.out.print( x[i]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        int [] y = new int [50];
        System.out.println("Values in array Y:"+"  ");
        for(int j =0; j < y.length; j++){

            y[j] = generator.nextInt(20);
            // count1 = count1 + 1;
            System.out.print(y[j]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        arrayTest(x,y);
    }

    public static void arrayTest (int x [] , int y[] )
    {
        int [] z = new int [50];
        // int [] b = new int [50];

        for(i = 0; i < (x.length); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <y.length; j++)
            {

                if (x[i] == y[j])
                {

                    z[c]=x[i];

                    c++;
                }
                else 
                    continue;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Values in array A:");
        for(k =0; k < c; k++)
        {
            System.out.print("  "+z[k]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("            ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Examine the stack trace and tell us upon which line the failure is happening.

Comment: the error is occurring at z[c]=x[i]; and arrayTest(x,y);

Comment: Just before that line, print out c and i. One should be weird. Use the debugger if you can - it's easier.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will handle duplicates too :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {3, 10, 4, 2, 8};
        int[] b = {10, 4, 12, 3, 23, 1, 8};
        int[] c = new int[(int)Math.min(a.length, b.length)];
        int i=0;
         for(int f=0;f<a.length;f++){
              for(int k=0;k<b.length;k++){
                    if( (a[f]==b[k]) && (doesArrayContainElement(c,a[f]) == false)) {
                    c[i] = a[f];
                    i++;
            }
          }
        }
        for (int x=0; x<i; x++){
           System.out.println(c[x]);
        }
       }
      public static boolean doesArrayContainElement(int array[], int element) {
          for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
           if(array[i] == element) {
                return true;
            }
          }
         return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: What does [(int)Math.min(a.length, b.length)] do?

Comment: it declares `int` array `c` with the size of either array `a` or `b`,depending on which of them has minimum size.

Comment: How is that handling duplicates? It's the same code as in the question (except of the initialization of the arrays). If a[] would be {3,10,4,4,8}, 4 would be added twice to the output array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't handle duplicates, which means that if both arrays have 50 identical numbers, you would attempt to insert 50*50 to the output array, whose size is only 50.

To solve this problem, you can maintain a `HashSet<Integer>` containing all the numbers added to the `z` array, and before adding a new number to `z`, check that it's not already in that Set.

Come to think of it, it's much better to hold the intersection in a Set instead of an array, since you don't know how many elements would be in it, so using an array (which has a fixed length) makes less sense. If you must, you can create an output array from the Set at the end.

A solution without Collections, which relies on the limited range of values `x` and `y` can hold :

```
public static void arrayTest (int x [] , int y[] )
{
    boolean[] z = new boolean[20];
    for(i = 0; i < (x.length); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                z[x[i]]=true;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Values in intersection:");
    for(k =0; k < z.length; k++) {
        if (z[k]) {
            System.out.print(" " + k + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("            ");
}
```

Comment: My teacher said I cant use anything but arrays, so no lists or hashsets. Im super new to all of this

Comment: @WisdomOrji In that case, you can rely on the fact that all the numbers in the arrays are between 0 and 19. `z` can be an array of 20 booleans, and when you find that x[i]==y[j], set z[x[i]] to true.

Comment: isn't z[x[i]] setting the contents of x[i] as the location for z? so like x[i] would = 10 then z[x[i]] would be z[10], or am i think about it too mathematically?

Comment: @WisdomOrji you are correct. If x[i]=10 z[x[i]] is z[10].

Comment: So how would that help me? Doesn't that force the loop to skip the previous slots for z?

Comment: @WisdomOrji The `z` array would hold booleans instead of integers. `z[i]` will be true if `i` is found in both `x` and `y` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void display(int A[], int n){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        System.out.print(A[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        HashSet hs = new HashSet(); 
        int A[] = new int[10];
        int B[] = new int[10];
        int c[] = new int[20],ctr=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            A[i] = r.nextInt(20);
            hs.add(A[i]);
            B[i] = r.nextInt(20);
        }
        display(A,10);
        display(B,10);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(hs.contains(B[i]))
            {c[ctr] = B[i];ctr++;}
        }
        display(c,ctr);

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the HashSet nor do I know what that is.